# Styling Part page with psvectorian

Tags: scrbook, psvectorian

Hi I would like to insert one of the psvectorian ornaments between the part number and part title.

It should look something like this:

[image]
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\begin{document}
\part{Part Name}
% \psvectorian[height=1cm]{102}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redefine `\partheadmidvskip` to insert the ornament:

```
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
  \psvectorian[height=1cm]{102}%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
  \psvectorian[height=1cm]{102}%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
}
\begin{document}
\part{Part Name}
\psvectorian[height=1cm]{102}
\end{document}
```

---

Update: If you want to insert the ornament over (`o`) or under (`u`) an unnumbered part as mentioned in a comment you can use `\setpartpreamble` before this `\part*` command:

```
\setpartpreamble[o]{%
  \centering\psvectorian[height=1cm]{102}%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
}
\part*{Unnumbered Part}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
  \psvectorian[height=1cm]{102}%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
}
\begin{document}
\setpartpreamble[o]{%
  \centering\psvectorian[height=1cm]{102}%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
}
\part*{Unnumbered Part}
Text
\part{Numbered Part}
Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly except in the case when part is made with the use of \part*{Part Name}. Do you by any chance know how to change that too?

Comment: Then you can use `\setpartpreamble`. I have added an example in my answer.