# How to insert an ornament between Part number and part title with psvectorian?

Tags: tufte, parts, pgfornament, psvectorian

I want to insert an ornament between the Part number and the Part title with psvectorian as explained in a previous question :

[Styling Part page with psvectorian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285783/styling-part-page-with-psvectorian)

Unfortunatly, it seems that there is a problem with the ornament I had chosen (which is 88) and the ornament goes on the following page of the part (and it is not centered), and not between the part number and the part title.
Where is the mistake ? Perhaps I need to use pgfornament ?

This is my code :

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
  \psvectorian[height=0.2cm]{88}%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{fullwidth}
\part{La Pi\`{e}ce d'Orgue \mbox{en \textit{r\'e} majeur} BWV 532}
\psvectorian[height=0.2cm]{88}
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to use `tufte-book` as documentclass or `scrbook`? The related question redefines the `\partheadmidvskip` command which does not exist for `tufte-book`, so you need another approach there. It should not even compile (i.e., give an error message). Maybe you compile with `nonstopmode` or something that ignores errors? In any case, the ornament seems to be coming from the second `\psvectorian` command (3rd line from the end in your code), that is indeed _after_ the title and not centered.

Comment: I want to use The Tufte-book documentclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % to use pstricks with pdflatex

\makeatletter
\def\H@old@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {%
     \begin{fullwidth}%
     \centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 10\p@
       \psvectorian[height=0.2cm]{88}\par
       \vskip 10\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par
     \end{fullwidth}%
    }%
    \@endpart}

% compact form (without fullwidth environment)
%\usepackage{xpatch}
%\xpatchcmd\H@old@part
%  {\vskip 20\p@}
%  {%
%    \vskip 10\p@
%    \psvectorian[height=0.2cm]{88}\par
%    \vskip 10\p@
%  }
%  {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{La Pi\`{e}ce d'Orgue \mbox{en \textit{r\'e} majeur} BWV 532}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There should be better solution, only because this one is more clear to me.

Comment: As I use XeLateX, I don't need the following line in your code: \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} , and it works ! Thanks !