# What is the best way to add a TikZ drawing to a \part{} page?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to position a Ti*k*Z drawing on a way too empty looking `\part{}` page. Is there any elegant solution to it that also allows positioning relative to the page?

Comment: You can insert an ornament? see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545697/how-to-insert-an-ornament-between-part-number-and-part-title-with-psvectorian

Comment: A lot depends on the document class.  Tikz [remember picture] can use (current page.center) for example.  Tikzpagenodes adds (current page text area.center) and others.

Comment: Or, you do `\clearpage` in front of the `\part`, then `\AddToNextHook{shipout/background}{\put(0,0){<your-picture-here>}}` (placement can be adjusted either via Ti*k*Z `current page` or by changing the first argument to `\put`).

Comment: I have a feeling that I provided an answer for this but I can't recall when I posted it.

Comment: I couldn't get the approach of Skillmon to work but I combined the solutions that Phil8544 and John Kormylo provided. Thanks y'all!